# Poles and Zeros exceptions

Tags: laplace-transform

If I have a function $\frac{s^2-10s-171}{s^4-30s^3+260s^2-1010s+779}$
and I factor the numerator and denominator and set them equal to zero like so:
$$s^4-30s^3+260s^2-1010s+779 = 0$$
$$s^2-10s-171 = 0$$
How come that when I solve for s and get 1, 19, 5+4j and 5-4j, that 19 is not a pole?

Also, when I solve for s to find zeros and get the following solutions: -9 and 19. Why is 19 not a zero here either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$\frac{(s+9)(s-19)}{(s-1)(s-19)(s^2-10s+41)}$$
the point $s=19$ is a hole and there exists a limit. The only pole is $s=1$.

Comment: Is it because poles and zeros can't be in the same spot?

Comment: Poles are not zeros.